# HiveQL: Merge array columns

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I have a table with columns having arrays, how to write HiveQL to merge the array columns?

```
| id | colA             | colB            | colC 
+----+------------------+-----------------+------------------    
| 1  | ["john", "james"]| ["peter"]       | ["sam","peter"]
| 2  | ["jane"]         | ["doug"]        | ["mary","peter"]
| 3  | ["jan", "james"] | ["peter","mary"]| ["sam","peter"]
```

Write query to display data like this:

```
| id | newcol
+----+------------------------------------------------------    
| 1  | ["john", "james", "peter", "sam","peter"]
| 2  | ["jane", "doug", "mary","peter"]
| 3  | ["jan", "james", "peter","mary","sam","peter"]
```

Comment: Do you want to display the data or do a new table ?

Comment: display the data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would like to create a new string array out of several string arrays, you can use the following (note that you need to check colB and colC for being empty, in order to avoid extra commas):

```
split (
concat (

concat_ws(',',colA),
if(size(colB)>0, concat(',', concat_ws(',',colB)), ''    ),
if(size(colC)>0, concat(',', concat_ws(',',colC)), ''    )


),',')
```

Answer (score 3):

```
hive> select split(concat_ws(',',array("john", "james"), array('peter'), array("sam","peter")), ",") as a;
OK
["john","james","peter","sam","peter"]
```

for your case.

```
select split(concat_ws(',',ColA, ColB, ColC), ",") as a;
```

Comment: does "concat_ws" accept multiple arrays as argument?

Comment: @mangusta i have `Hive 1.2.1000` and it works. not sure about any other version.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that :

[Concat or ||](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-StringOperators)

```
SELECT id, colA||','||colB||','||colC AS newcol FROM myTable
```

OR

```
SELECT id, Concat(colA,',',colB,',',colC,) AS newcol FROM myTable
```

Comment: which hive version are you using, for me it says `CONCAT only takes primitive arguments`

Comment: Note that if any of `colA`/`colB`/`colC` is `NULL`, the whole `concat` output is `NULL`, which may not be desireable